# How to print a 2D array in a "pretty" format?

Tags: python, arrays, list, 2d

Hello so let's say I have a 2D array `a = [[1,2,1,2], [3,4,5,3], [8,9,4,3]]` and I would like to print this out in a grid like table. So far the code I have is:

```
def printArray(a):
    for row in range(len(a[0])):
        for col in range (len(a[0])):
            b = print("{:8.3f}".format(a[row][col]), end = " ")
        print(b)
```

When this is printed out it gives me:

```
  1.000    2.000    1.000    2.000 None
  3.000    4.000    5.000    3.000 None
  8.000    9.000    4.000    3.000 None
```

And then the error:

```
File "hw8pr2.py", line 17, in printArray
b = print("{:8.3f}".format(a[row][col]), end = " ")

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can someone tell me why this is happening? I don't want the 'None' at the end of each row either. I want it to output:

```
  1.000    2.000    1.000    2.000
  3.000    4.000    5.000    3.000
  8.000    9.000    4.000    3.000
```

Comment: You don't need to declare a variable to print out things. It's returning none because the variable b doesn't actually have anything once the for loop with variable b is over. Remove the last line.

Comment: You are using `len(a[0])` for both columns and rows. If you have a sqare matrix it would work, but this is not the case for the example you have given.

Comment: To print pretty tables, Python has a module cleverly named [prettytable](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PTable/0.9.2).

Answer (score 2):

Here is what your are using:

```
def printArray(a):
    for row in range(len(a[0])):
        for col in range (len(a[0])):
            b = print("{:8.3f}".format(a[row][col]), end = " ")
        print(b)
```

You are using two for loops with `len(a[0])` but your input data isn't a square, so that can't work!

You might consider using this:

```
def printA(a):
    for row in a:
        for col in row:
            print("{:8.3f}".format(col), end=" ")
        print("")
```

That will give you this:

```
In [14]: a = [[1, 2, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 3], [8, 9, 4, 3]]

In [15]: printA(a)
   1.000    2.000    1.000    2.000 
   3.000    4.000    5.000    3.000 
   8.000    9.000    4.000    3.000 

In [16]: b = [[1, 2, 1, 2, 5], [3, 4, 7, 5, 3], [8, 2, 9, 4, 3], [2, 8, 4, 7, 6]]

In [17]: printA(b)
   1.000    2.000    1.000    2.000    5.000 
   3.000    4.000    7.000    5.000    3.000 
   8.000    2.000    9.000    4.000    3.000 
   2.000    8.000    4.000    7.000    6.000
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three main issues with the code you have posted: the way of iterating through the array, the assignment of the `b` variable to a the return of a `print` statement, and the printing of that `b` variable.

Firstly, the way you are iterating through the array is fairly counter-intuitive. You can simply use

```
def printArray(arr):
    for row in arr:
        for item in row:
            # code for printing
```

to make it much more clear.

Secondly, your understanding of the `print` statement seems to be a bit lacking. The `print` statement takes in an argument and prints it out directly, so there is no need to assign it to a variable. Since the print statement has no official return, it automatically returns `None`, which ties in with the next point to explain the `None`s at the end of your print statements.

Finally, the printing of the `b` variable which has a value `None` assigned to it as discussed above produces the `None`s you see.

---

To fix your code, you could use the following solution.

```
a = [[1,2,1,2], [3,4,5,3], [8,9,4,3]]

def printArray(arr):
    for row in arr:
        for item in row:
            print("{:8.3f}".format(item), end = " ")
        print("")

printArray(a)
```

Other than the things stated above, this code differs by adding a `print("")`, which is equivalent to a new line, after every row in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You are using len(a[0]) in both loops.

use

```
for row in range(len(a)):
  for col in range(len(a[0])):
```

Answer (score 0):

You got the first range wrong (and the second one should take the length of the current row) and you don't need a variable b:

```
def printArray(a):
    for row in range(len(a)):
        for col in range (len(a[row])):
            print("{:8.3f}".format(a[row][col]), end = " ")
        print()
```